# Rotating entire X,Y axis in 2D space via matplotlib

Tags: python, math, matrix, 3d

I have problem using matplotlib in Python. Problem is that I must make rotation in 2D of X and Y axis by 30°,45°,60° and 120° and the opposite. In this code below can someone please give me some tips how to make rotations of axis.
Note: There has to be visible 2 pairs of axis, one original,black and rotated which is in this case green.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from pylab import 

axis([-5,5,-5,5]) #original axis x,y
axvline(x=0, ymin=0, linewidth=1, color='k')
axhline(y=0, xmin=0, linewidth=1, color='k')


t_start1 = axvline(x=0, ymin=0, linewidth=2, color='g') #rotated y coordinate
t_start2 = axhline(y=0, xmin=0, linewidth=2, color='g') #rotated x coordinate

scatter([0],[0],color="k",s=30,label="S = (0,0)")
scatter([2],[1],color="b",s=30,label="A = (2,1)")
scatter([2.23],[-0.13],color="r",s=40,label="A' = (2.23,-0.13)")

legend(loc=0)
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
title('Rotation by 30° Right coordinate system ');

grid()
plt.show()
```

*[image: current situation]

Comment: Why is this tagged matlab?

Comment: Why not? People share interest..if someone uses matlab they might know how to make in mathplot

Comment: I don't think there is a built in solution for this. But how do you think about using a polar plot, maybe this would represent your problem/solution better?

Comment: @pwagner You are right, there is no solution, but i calculated one  coordinate of rotated axis and as it must go trought (0,0) i made line trough  2 points with adding:
plot([-5, 0 , 5], [-5, 0, 5], color='r',)
plot([-5, 0 , 5], [5, 0,-5],  color='r',)

and I got "rotated" axis just put in coordinates of calculated point which is on  rotated axis and that's it...